# How to access the Share option from CharmBar in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am programming in C# for Windows Store apps but i am new to this platform. In my application i want to implement the share contract option when user click the Share button from Charm Bar.

I could see only SettingsPane and SearchPane API to access Settings and Search options but was not able to find anything with the name of SharePane. Is there any way to access the Share click handling in Windows Store apps ?

Comment: Hope this helps: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am showing you the basic usage of share charm. In my example we will share text content from text box

1. `DataTransferManager` class does all the sharing. So first you will need the current instance of that class and invoke `DataRequested` event. So you have to assign event in `OnNavigatedTo` event & release event in `OnNavigatedFrom` event.
2. If you want to open share charm programmatically then write `DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();` in button's click event.

Code for the sample.

C#

```
DataTransferManager dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    dataTransferManager.DataRequested += ShareTextHandler;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    dataTransferManager.DataRequested -= ShareTextHandler;
}

private void ShareTextHandler(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRequest request = e.Request;
    request.Data.Properties.Title = "Share Text Example"; // You must have to set title.
    request.Data.Properties.Description = "A demonstration that shows how to share text.";
    request.Data.SetText(ShareText.Text);
}
private void Share_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
}
```

XAML

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Width="500" Height="200" x:Name="ShareText" />
        <Button Content="Share" Click="Share_Click_1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[MSDN Sample App](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84)

[Quickstart: Sharing content (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh871368.aspx)